# Ground "draining off" charge - Griffiths Problem 2.38

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I'm currently reading through Griffiths Electrodynamics 4ed and I'm struggling with problem 2.38c (see attached picture of question and solution).

I get that, using his statement that the potential goes to 0 after grounding, I can show that there must be a charge of -q on the outer shell (using that information) since potential is now 0 all the way to radius a from infinity, requiring E=0 everywhere up to a. Generally speaking, it makes sense that potential goes to 0, but I'm curious as to how we can show or know this. That is, if I had not known a priori that potential was 0 over the surface after grounding, I could not have solved the problem, and yet I'm certain that there must be a way of solving it without using that (extraneous) piece of info.

I'm therefore wondering if anyone can provide me with the intuition for why the surface charge on the shell at b drains off as opposed to any other possibility. It is not immediately clear to me that +q should drain off (though I generally get that this is charging by induction).

Thanks!

[image: Question]
[image: Solution]

Comment: I don't see any attached pictures. In any case, it is much better to type out the relevant parts of what you are talking about than post a picture. Pictures are not accessible to all users. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations / variables

Comment: You're absolutely right, I completely forgot to add them - my bad! I did end up adding the picture because I think the included diagram as well as Griffiths' rather short assertion about charge draining off were the crux of my problem.

Comment: The picture of the figure is fine. But for text and equations it is preferred you just type those out.

Comment: "Grounding" and "setting potential to zero" are synonyms.

Comment: I think maybe you could edit the question to say, “if I were instead given that +q were added to the outer shell, how would I solve this?” And even bold that part. If thats indeed what youre asking. Or come up with something specific like that. Im not sure the answers addressed the core question, and we are dealing w engineers and physicists lol. Just a thought. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the shell has no charge.

There is a charge $q$ on the sphere. Hence the flux of the electric field one every closed surface enclosing this sphere, in particular any spherical surface with the same center, will be $q/\epsilon_0$, as long as there is no possibility to have any more charge inside the sphere, that is, in the vacuum between the sphere and the inner surface of the shell.

Within the shell, which is a conductor there can be no  electric field. Thus the charge within any sphere included in the shell must be zero. Therefore there must be a charge $-q$ on this inner surface, so that the global charge included in any sphere within the shell be zero.

But in the first case the shell is neutral, no net charge. If a charge $-q$ is located on its inner surface, a balancing charge $q$ must be located in the only other possible place, its outer surface.

Any sphere in the vacuum outside the shell therefore encloses the $q$ charge on the sphere, $-q$ on the inner surface of the shell and $q$ on the outer surface, (a global zero charge coming from the entire shell which is neutral). Hence the field in the vacuum between the outer surface of the shell and infinity, the same field as if there were no shell, but only the charge $q$ of the sphere.

Now in the second case, you touch the shell with a "grounding wire". For people who work with electricity (like my father, who had a degree an Electrical Engineering and taught me all about it) the word "grounding" is a technical term meaning bringing **perforce** the potential of the "grounded object" to that of the **reference point** which, in the case of this problem is infinity. Sinking a wire into very dry earth, as you suggest in your comment to R.W. Bird's answer, is not "grounding". If in your bathroom you try to "ground" your water pipes by connecting them to a metal post just randomly sunk into the earth, you can easily get electrocuted. "Grounding" is serious business.

Thus the shell being "grounded" means that it has **the same potential as infinity**. Hence there can be no electric field outside it, no electric flux on any sphere enclosing it, and thus the net charge inside any such sphere must be zero. Since there is already a charge $q$ on the sphere and a charge $-q$ on the inner surface of the shell, this shows that there must be **no more charge** on its outer surface. The charge that was there in the first case has **entirely** been drained by the "grounding" wire.

Otherwise, the wire would just not **deserve the name "grounding"**.

I hope this is now intuitive enough.

Answer (score 0):

How can you define the ground if you don't have any extraneous information? Just as it happens, in finite charge distributions, selecting $|\mathbf r|\to\infty$ as $V=0$ has its perks, such as it being the canonical ground while using $V(\mathbf r)=\sum_{i}\frac{q_i}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_i|}$, corresponding to there being no charges at all. Any other attempt to define a ground will ignore this fact. In the end calculations would work out by why not just select the standard one?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a power source, there can be no E field inside of a conductor. (If there were such a field, free charges would move until there was no field.)  This means that every point in the conductor must be at the same potential. The “ground” in an electrostatics problem is defined as having a potential of zero.  Any conductor connected to the “ground” (as by a wire) must come to that zero potential.

Comment: Is this true in general? Suppose the ground were some insulator and the conductor were in contact with it. You could conceive of there then being surface charge at the interface so that the conductor were not then at $V=0$.

Comment: @1729_SR See my answer "ground" in electrical engineering parlance is not just some piece of soil. It has the precise meaning of bringing the potential to some assigned value. Here it says explicitly that "ground" is the potential at infinity. In other circumstances it could be defined in a different way, but it is always unambiguous. For instance, within a car, the "ground" is the main body of the car. If the rubber tyres are insulator, the potential of the body can be very different from the potential at infinity. But all the electronics in the car better be "grounded" to the main body !